# XEN access folder across VMs

Tags: virtual-machine, share, xen

I have a XEN server hosting some Windows and Linux clients and I want them to be able to share certain files. So I decided to create one VM (currently running under fedora linux) which does all the mounting stuff (which is very complex in this case). I made it all up so that this mounting-VM contains n folders, one for each VM to share files with. These folders content overlaps internally (using symlinks).

My question is now, how do I connect these folders to the VMs that should have access to them?

There are certain requirements however:

1) No VM should be able to access a folder that it is not meant to access (assuming that an attacker is root on the VM, some of the VMs have network access).

2) No one from the outside should be able to access any of these folders. Connections to the outside go all through a firewall-VM and dom0 has no network access, because the network-card is directly attached to the firewall-VM. So this shall not be too hard.

In the ideal case, I would like to even assign different priviledges based on which VM accesses a certain folder, but this is not required. I would prefer simple solutions over flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I made part of the solution and I'd like to share my results with you:

My plan is to use n different pure-ftpd instances in standalone and anonymous only mode listening on different ports. I also looked at samba and nfs, but these two solutions are not easy to make secure (at least in my opinion). With FTP I can rely on my firewall securing the ports. Using FTP and not e.g. samba, the user has no control over a local user account aside from file access. So the potential attack surface should be smaller.

I'm now working on the port-forwarding stuff (my firewall is iptables). I'll let you know, when I make further progress.